# Problems programmatically connecting to AD

Tags: java, active-directory

I'm developing a Java EE 6 application that uses AD to help with logging in. My authenticator is simple and looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ADAuthenticator{
    private static final String ldapHost = "ldap://domainname.mycompany.com:389";
    private static final String domain = "domainname";

    public ADAuthenticator() {
    }

    public void authenticate(String user, String pass) throws NamingException{
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
        LdapContext ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    }
}
```

This has worked well for some time, but lately I'm getting the following exception (except some times where it magically works):

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: mydomain.mycompany.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:210)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:118)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1580)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2652)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134)
at com.xdin.competence.util.ADAuthenticator.authenticate(ADAuthenticator.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at <ejb stuff omitted> 

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:352)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:187)
... 101 more
```

Nothing has changed with the code, and according to IT-support, no configuration regarding AD has been changed either.

I seperated the relevant code into a simple console application, and it works perfectly with the exact same settings. So the problem seems related to Java EE or the webserver. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The packets for the TCP/IP connection do not arrive in time.  This may have multiple reasons, but from what you describe, this may simply be a network congestion between your Java code and the LDAP server which in turn causes package loss.  There might also be a firewall blocking that port inbetween.

You need to learn about the `ping`, `traceroute` and `telnet host port` tools to troubleshoot your network layer.  I would suggest you team up with a network guy from IT-support and ask him nicely to help finding out where your package loss is.

Comment: +1. This has all the hallmarks of network issues. Also, dont forget to check the NIC (network card) on your server (and on the AD). That's one of those things that usually people assumes will never happen, but it's surprising how often NIC:s break. Easiest way to check is to try and run your app on another physical machine, or throw in a new NIC temporarily (you can get a cheap ethernet card OTC for virtually nothing).

Comment: Tried seperating the AD part from my project into a SE application, and it works flawlessly. So I guess I can rule out any hardware problem. Looks like some issue with Java EE/webserver stuff

Comment: @Rasmus, depends on where your SE application ran.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I'm facing the same issue, and I could ping the server's machine. is there a way to trace the package from my local machine to see if it arrives to the server (even if I think that the response is no )

Comment: @aName Yes.  Depending on your platform you should have either "tracert" or "traceroute" available (or installable).  This will help you troubleshoot the network connections.

Comment: when I use tracert in windows here is what I get :

Comment: Détermination de l'itinéraire vers x.y.z.u avec un maximum de 30 sauts.
1 <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  x.y.z.u
2  *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
3  *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
4 66 ms    67 ms    66 ms  x.a.b.c
5    67 ms    66 ms    67 ms  x.a.b.d
6  *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
7 66 ms    67 ms    67 ms  x.a.e.f
8 70 ms    78 ms    72 ms  x.a.e.g
9 65 ms    66 ms    65 ms  x.a.h.i
10 66 ms    65 ms    66 ms  x.a.h.i

Comment: So that works. Now telnet to the port on your host where AD lives.

Comment: here is what I get when I run telnet x.y.z.u 389 :  ...Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à l'hôte, sur le port 389: Échec lors de la connexion

Comment: If I understand the french correctly, you cannot connect even if you can ping it.  Talk to your network supporter!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155922/discussion-between-aname-and-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen).